# How can I transfer an eclipse project to a new computer?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am new to C++ and Eclipse (with CDT plugin) and I want to transfer the small project I have written on my old computer to my new one. On the new machine, must I create a new project, new files for each corresponding file in the project, then copy and paste the source into these files, or is there a setting in Eclipse that would allow me to import the files in one go. I have been searching all of the menu items for something such as "import project" or "import files" but I cannot find anything. Is copy and paste the only solution? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create a new and empty Workspace.

Then open the **File** menu and select **Import...**.

Here you'll find an option to import existing projects, which should work with the project file in your old/copied source directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Create project from existing source: When selected, you can specify the location from which the New Java Project Wizard will
>   retrieve an existing Java project. In this case the wizard will
>   analyze the existing project and set up the build path automatically. 
>   Click on Browse... to browse for a location of an existing Java
>   project.

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-wizard-java-project.htm

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to copy the complete workspace folder.